# ASP.net Search function edit

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-like

I have been asked to edit a search function in someone elses code.

I don't have a huge amount of knowledge in this particular language and although I'm sure its an easy fix, I don't want to break it without advice.

The search function is bringing back too many results, its searching part words. So seaching "e" would bring back verything with an "e" in it..

I need to edit to to search the full word.

Here is the entire code.

```
    <!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/config.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/folder-string-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/database-open.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/field-filtering-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/login-checker.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/date-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/form-counter.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/email-check-code-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/trimstring-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/toilehighlighter-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/paging-functions.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/regular-expression-functions.asp" -->
<%
lightboxgallery = "Yes"

searchfor = fieldfiltering(Request("searchfor"))
searchfor = TRIM(searchfor)
IF RIGHT(searchfor, 1) = "/" then searchfor = LEFT(searchfor, LEN(searchfor)-1)

seotitle = "Tube Tech International - search results for: " & searchfor
seodescription = "Tube Tech International search results for: " & searchfor
seokeywords = "Tube Tech International, " & searchfor

Session("searchedfor") = searchfor
Session("searchedfortime") = now()
%>

<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/template/template-start.asp" -->

<%

'#### Paging ####
thispage = id1
If NOT ISNUMERIC(thispage) OR thispage = "" then 
thispage = 1
Else
thispage = CINT(thispage)
End If
'#################

%>

<div id="breadcrumbs">
<form action="/search/" method="get" class="searchform"><input type="submit" name="submit" tabindex="2" value="Search" class="search-click" /><input type="text" tabindex="1" value="Type your search here" onfocus="this.value=''" name="searchfor" class="search-box" /></form>
<a href="/"><img src="/images/home.png" alt="Home" width="12" height="12" class="home" border="0" /></a>
<a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#">Search for: <i><% =searchfor %></i></a>
</div> 

<div id="searchcontent">

    <div class="leftbox">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <p class="opening"><b>Your search results: <% =searchfor %></b></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

   <% If searchfor <> "" then %>    

   <div class="rightbox">
        <h2>Photo Gallery</h2>
        <p>Click the images for a larger view.</p>

        <div id="gallery">

            <%

            listingstringloop = ""
            listingstring = ""
            counterdiv = 0

            strSQL = ""

            strSQL        = "SELECT 'case-studies' AS pagetype, cs.title AS entrytitle, cs.casestudyid AS id, csi.casestudyimageid AS imageid, csi.imagetitle,  LIKE (cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance, LIKE (csi.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS imagerelevance "

            strSQL = strSQL & "FROM casestudies AS cs, casestudiesimages AS csi "

            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE cs.casestudyid = csi.casestudyid AND cs.modestatus = '1' AND ((LIKE(csi.imagetitle) OR (cs.title like '%"& searchfor & "%') OR (cs.content like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (csi.imagetitle like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "

            strSQL = strSQL & "UNION ALL "


            strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT 'news' AS pagetype, news.title AS entrytitle, news.newsid AS id, newsimages.newsimageid AS imageid, newsimages.imagetitle, LIKE (news.title, news.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance, LIKE (newsimages.imagetitle) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS imagerelevance "

            strSQL = strSQL & "FROM news, newsimages "

            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE news.newsid = newsimages.newsid AND news.modestatus = '1' AND ((news.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (news.content like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (newsimages.imagetitle like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "

            strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "

            strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC, imagerelevance DESC "


            Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

            If rsSearch.EOF = False then

            counter = 1

               Do while NOT rsSearch.eof 

                If counter > 2 then counter = 1       

                thisid = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
                thistitle = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("entrytitle"))
                imageid = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("imageid"))
                pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
                imagetitle = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("imagetitle"))

                listingstring = "<a href=""/images/" & pagetype & "/images/" & imageid & "-3.jpg"" class=""normal"" title=""" & imagetitle

                If pagetype = "case-studies" then
                listingstring = listingstring & "<br />To read the case study in full please <a href='http://www.tubetech.com" & buildlink("/case-studies/" & thisid & "_" & thistitle & "/") & "'>click here</a>"
                ElseIf pagetype = "news" then
                listingstring = listingstring & "<br />To read the news story in full please <a href='http://www.tubetech.com" & buildlink("/news/" & thisid & "_" & thistitle & "/") & "'>click here</a>"
                End If

                listingstring = listingstring & """>"

                listingstring = listingstring & "<img src=""/images/" & pagetype & "/transparent.gif"" style=""background-image:url('/images/" & pagetype & "/images/" & imageid & "-1.jpg');background-position:center;"" width=""115"" height=""86"" alt=""" & imagetitle & """ title=""" & imagetitle & """ "
                If counter = 1 then 
                    listingstring = listingstring & "class=""left"""
                Else 
                    listingstring = listingstring & "class=""right"""
                End If 
                listingstring = listingstring & "/></a>" & vbcrlf

                listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring

            counter = counter + 1
            counterdiv= counterdiv + 1    
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop        
            %>

                <div class="photocontainer"<% If counterdiv < 7 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
                <div id="photocontent" style="overflow: hidden;">

                <% =listingstringloop %>

                </div>
                </div>

            <%          
            End if 

            rsSearch.Close
            Set rsSearch = Nothing

            %>              

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftbox">

        <% If searchfor <> "" then %>


            <%

            searchrecordin = "No"

            listingstringloop = ""
            listingstring = ""
            counterleftbox = 0

            strSQL = ""
            strSQL  = "SELECT 'case-studies' AS pagetype, cs.casestudyid AS id, cs.title, cs.content, 0 AS menutype, '' AS menuoption, LIKE (cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance FROM casestudies AS cs "          
            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE cs.modestatus = '1' AND (LIKE(cs.title, cs.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR (cs.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (cs.content like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "           
            strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
            strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY lastupdated DESC "
'           strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC "            
            Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

            If rsSearch.EOF = False then
            searchrecordin = "Yes"
            %>
            <h2 class="section">Case studies</h2>
            <%          
                Do while NOT rsSearch.eof            

                id = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
                pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
                title = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("title"))
                menutype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menutype"))
                menuoption = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menuoption"))

                content = rsSearch("content")
                content = reversefieldfiltering(content)
                content = striptags(content)
                content = trimstring(content, 148)
                content = toilehighlighter(content, searchfor)
                content = content & "..."

                If pagetype = "web-pages" then
                    If menutype = "1" then              
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & title & "/")             
                    ElseIf menutype = "2" then
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & menuoption & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/")               
                    End If  
                Else

                    linkname = buildlink("/" & pagetype & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/") 

                End If

                title = toilehighlighter(title, searchfor)

                listingstring = "<h3><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & title & "</a></h3>" & vbcrlf
                listingstring = listingstring & "<p class=""opening""><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & content & "</a></p>" & vbcrlf

                listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring


            counterleftbox = counterleftbox + 1
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop
            %>

            <div class="casestudiescontainer"<% If counterleftbox < 5 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
            <div id="casestudiescontent">
            <% =listingstringloop %>        
            </div>
            </div>

            <% End if 

            rsSearch.Close
            Set rsSearch = Nothing  
            %>


            <%

            listingstringloop = ""
            listingstring = ""
            counterleftbox = 0

    strSQL = ""
                strSQL = "SELECT 'news' AS pagetype, news.newsid AS id, news.title, news.content, 0 AS menutype, '' AS menuoption, LIKE (news.title, news.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance FROM news "
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE news.modestatus = '1' AND (LIKE(news.title, news.content) OR (news.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (news.content like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "           
    strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC "
                Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

            If rsSearch.EOF = False then
            searchrecordin = "Yes"
            %>          
            <h2 class="section">News</h2>            
            <%
                Do while NOT rsSearch.eof 

                id = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
                pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
                title = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("title"))
                menutype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menutype"))
                menuoption = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menuoption"))

                content = rsSearch("content")
                content = reversefieldfiltering(content)
                content = striptags(content)
                content = trimstring(content, 148)
                content = toilehighlighter(content, searchfor)
                content = content & "..."

                If pagetype = "web-pages" then
                    If menutype = "1" then              
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & title & "/")             
                    ElseIf menutype = "2" then
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & menuoption & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/")               
                    End If  
                Else

                    linkname = buildlink("/" & pagetype & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/") 

                End If              

                title = toilehighlighter(title, searchfor)

                listingstring = "<h3><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & title & "</a></h3>" & vbcrlf
                listingstring = listingstring & "<p class=""opening""><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & content & "</a></p>" & vbcrlf

                listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring

            counterleftbox = counterleftbox + 1
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop

            %>

            <div class="newscontainer"<% If counterleftbox < 5 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
            <div id="newscontent">  
            <% =listingstringloop %>        
            </div>
            </div>

            <% End if 

            rsSearch.Close
            Set rsSearch = Nothing  
            %>

            <%

            listingstringloop = ""
            listingstring = ""
            counterleftbox = 0

            strSQL = ""
            strSQL = "SELECT 'techniques' AS pagetype, tech.techniqueid AS id, tech.title, tech.content, 0 AS menutype, '' AS menuoption, LIKE (tech.title, tech.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance FROM techniques AS tech "
            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE tech.modestatus = '1' AND (LIKE(tech.title, tech.content) OR (tech.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (tech.content like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "           
            strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
            strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC "
            Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

            If rsSearch.EOF = False then            
            searchrecordin = "Yes"
            %>          
            <h2 class="section">Techniques</h2>               
            <%

                Do while NOT rsSearch.eof            

                id = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
                pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
                title = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("title"))
                menutype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menutype"))
                menuoption = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menuoption"))

                content = rsSearch("content")
                content = reversefieldfiltering(content)
                content = striptags(content)
                content = trimstring(content, 148)
                content = toilehighlighter(content, searchfor)
                content = content & "..."

                If pagetype = "web-pages" then
                    If menutype = "1" then              
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & title & "/")             
                    ElseIf menutype = "2" then
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & menuoption & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/")               
                    End If  
                Else

                    linkname = buildlink("/" & pagetype & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/") 

                End If              

                title = toilehighlighter(title, searchfor)

                listingstring = "<h3><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & title & "</a></h3>" & vbcrlf
                listingstring = listingstring & "<p class=""opening""><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & content & "</a></p>" & vbcrlf

                listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring   

            counterleftbox = counterleftbox + 1                 
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop
            %>

            <div class="techniquescontainer"<% If counterleftbox < 5 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
            <div id="techniquescontent">
            <% =listingstringloop %>        
            </div>
            </div>

            <% End if 

            rsSearch.Close
            Set rsSearch = Nothing  
            %>


            <%

            listingstringloop = ""
            listingstring = ""
            counterleftbox = 0

            strSQL = ""
            strSQL = "SELECT 'web-pages' AS pagetype, pages.pageid AS id, pages.title, pages.content, pages.menutype, pages.menuoption, LIKE (pages.title, pages.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance FROM webpages AS pages "
            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE pages.modestatus = '1' AND (LIKE(pages.title, pages.content) OR (pages.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (pages.content like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "          
            strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
            strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC "
            Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

            If rsSearch.EOF = False then
            searchrecordin = "Yes"          
            %>          
            <h2 class="section">Web Pages</h2>               
            <%
                Do while NOT rsSearch.eof            

                id = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
                pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
                title = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("title"))
                menutype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menutype"))
                menuoption = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menuoption"))

                content = rsSearch("content")
                content = reversefieldfiltering(content)
                content = striptags(content)
                content = trimstring(content, 148)
                content = toilehighlighter(content, searchfor)
                content = content & "..."

                If pagetype = "web-pages" then
                    If menutype = "1" then              
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & title & "/")             
                    ElseIf menutype = "2" then
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & menuoption & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/")               
                    End If  
                Else

                    linkname = buildlink("/" & pagetype & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/") 

                End If              

                title = toilehighlighter(title, searchfor)

                listingstring = "   <h3><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & title & "</a></h3>" & vbcrlf
                listingstring = listingstring & "   <p class=""opening""><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & content & "</a></p>" & vbcrlf

                listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring   

            counterleftbox = counterleftbox + 1         
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop
            %>

            <div class="webpagescontainer"<% If counterleftbox < 5 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
            <div id="webpagescontent">
             <% =listingstringloop %>               
            </div>
            </div>

            <% End if 

            rsSearch.Close
            Set rsSearch = Nothing  
            %>


            <%

            listingstringloop = ""
            listingstring = ""
            counterleftbox = 0

            strSQL = ""
            strSQL = "SELECT 'categories' AS pagetype, cat.categoryid AS id, cat.category AS title, cat.content, 0 AS menutype, '' AS menuoption, LIKE (cat.category, cat.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance FROM categories AS cat "
            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (LIKE(cat.category, cat.content) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR (cat.category like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (cat.content like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "                     
            strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
            strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC "
            Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

            If rsSearch.EOF = False then
            searchrecordin = "Yes"          
            %>          
            <h2 class="section">Categories</h2>                  
            <%
                Do while NOT rsSearch.eof            

                id = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
                pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
                title = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("title"))
                menutype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menutype"))
                menuoption = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("menuoption"))

                content = rsSearch("content")
                content = reversefieldfiltering(content)
                content = striptags(content)
                content = trimstring(content, 148)
                content = toilehighlighter(content, searchfor)
                content = content & "..."

                If pagetype = "web-pages" then
                    If menutype = "1" then              
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & title & "/")             
                    ElseIf menutype = "2" then
                        linkname = buildlink("/" & menuoption & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/")               
                    End If  
                Else

                    linkname = buildlink("/" & pagetype & "/" & id & "_" & title & "/") 

                End If

                title = toilehighlighter(title, searchfor)

                listingstring = "   <h3><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & title & "</a></h3>" & vbcrlf
                listingstring = listingstring & "   <p class=""opening""><a href=""" & linkname & """>" & content & "</a></p>" & vbcrlf

                listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring   

            counterleftbox = counterleftbox + 1         
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop
            %>

            <div class="categoriescontainer"<% If counterleftbox < 5 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
            <div id="categoriescontent" style="width: auto;">
             <% =listingstringloop %>                   
            </div>
            </div>

            <% End if 

            rsSearch.Close
            Set rsSearch = Nothing  


            If searchrecordin = "No" then
            %>
                <p class="opening"><b>We are sorry, but no matches were found matching your search term. Please try a different search term.</b></p>
            <%
            End If

        End If %>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="rightbox">
        <h2>Video Gallery</h2>    

        <%  

        listingstringloop = ""
        listingstring = ""
        counterdiv = 0

        strSQL = ""
        strSQL  = "SELECT 'video-gallery' AS pagetype, vg.videogalleryid AS id, vg.title, vg.videocontent, vg.folderlink, LIKE (vg.title, vg.description) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "') AS relevance FROM videogallery AS vg "          
        strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (LIKE(vg.title, vg.description) AGAINST ('" & searchfor & "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR (vg.title like '%" & searchfor & "%') OR (vg.description like '%" & searchfor & "%')) "           
        strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY id "
        strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY relevance DESC "            
        Set rsSearch = my_conn.Execute(strSQL)

        If rsSearch.EOF = False then            

        imagecounter = 1

            Do while NOT rsSearch.eof 

            If imagecounter > 2 then imagecounter = 1

            youtubevideoid = ""

            id = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("id"))
            pagetype = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("pagetype"))
            videotitle = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("title"))
            folderlink = reversefieldfiltering(rsSearch("folderlink"))      
            videocontent = rsSearch("videocontent")
            videocontent = reversefieldfiltering(videocontent)

            regExpVideocontent = Replace(videocontent, "v/","#v=")      
            youtubevideoid = GetFirstMatch("[\\#&]v=([^?#]*)",regExpVideocontent)

            If youtubevideoid = "" then

                regExpVideocontent = GetFirstMatch("<iframe [^>]*src=""(.*?)""[^>]*>",videocontent)
                regExpVideocontent = Replace(regExpVideocontent,"http://www.youtube.com/embed/","")
                regExpVideocontent = Replace(regExpVideocontent,"?rel=0","")
                youtubevideoid = TRIM(regExpVideocontent)
                youtubevideoid = RTRIM(youtubevideoid)
                youtubevideoid = LTRIM(youtubevideoid)

            End If      


            listingstring = "   <a href=""/video-gallery/?a=1&vgid=" & id & """>"
            listingstring = listingstring & "<img src=""/images/transparent.gif"" style=""background-image:url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/" & youtubevideoid & "/1.jpg');background-position:center;"" border=""0"" width=""115"" height=""86"" alt=""" & videotitle & """ title=""" & videotitle & """ "
            If imagecounter = 1 then 
            listingstring = listingstring & "class=""left"""
            Else 
            listingstring = listingstring & "class=""right"""
            End If
            listingstring = listingstring & "/></a>" & vbcrlf

            listingstringloop = listingstringloop & listingstring       

            imagecounter = imagecounter + 1
            counterdiv = counterdiv + 1 
            rsSearch.MoveNext
            loop

          %>

            <div class="videocontainer"<% If counterdiv < 7 then %> style="height:auto;"<% End If %>>
            <div id="videocontent">                
            <% =listingstringloop %>
            </div>
            </div>

          <%
          End if 

          rsSearch.Close
          Set rsSearch = Nothing        
          %>   

    </div>

    <% End If %> 

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/template/template-end.asp" -->
<!-- #include virtual="/site-elements/includes/database-close.asp" -->
```

Generally I use a % to mark my part and full words. So cant work out where he is setting this...

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: Could you please post the Back End code as well? The C# code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a word then you can use the following idea.

Call the following line before constructing the SQL

```
searchfor = "[^a-zA-Z]" + searchfor + "[^a-zA-Z]"
```

The idea here is to search for entered content where it has no alphabets before and after it. For example if you enter 'at' then it matches 'car at usa' but not 'cat'

This is not perfect solution, but just an idea, this can be extended to exclude further charectors